# Alignment of minted line numbers

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minted

I'm using the [`minted`](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) package for code highlighting. The below is just a minimal example. What I find annoying about this package is that line numbers appear in the margin.

[image]

This causes several problems with `\item`s but also in `twocolumn` articles. What I would like is to have the line numbers aligned with the normal text, like so:

[image]

I have read through the documentation, but there doesn't seem to be such an option. The `numbers=right` option doesn't help me either: I don't want numbers on the right, and even if I would, that option places numbers in the right *margin*.

I have tried putting it altogether in a minipage (i.e. `\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\begin{minted} ... \end{minted}\end{minipage}`), but couldn't get spacing work properly.

What would be the preferred way to move the numbers to the right?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{minted}[linenos,breaklines]{text}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{minted}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `xleftmargin`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{minted,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=\parindent,linenos,breaklines]{text}
Donec vehicula augue eu neque.
Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo.
Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem.
Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices.
\end{minted}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may also want to modify `numbersep`; the default is `numbersep=12pt`.

For instance, if you want that the line numbers (two digits) are flush with the left margin, you can do

```
\newlength{\mintednumbersep}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \sbox0{\tiny00}%
  \setlength\mintednumbersep{\parindent}%
  \addtolength\mintednumbersep{-\wd0}%
}
```

and then set `numbersep=\mintednumbersep`.

Comment: I searched for `number` in the documentation, not for `margin`... Thanks!

Comment: If you are using the `parskip` package, a quick-and-dirty solution is to replace `xleftmargin=\parindent` by `xleftmargin=0.475em` (or whichever length suits your document). To make it apply across all `minted` environments, add `\setminted{xleftmargin=...}` to your preamble.

Comment: @Mew I *never* use `parskip`.  */harsh voice like Bela Lugosi*

Comment: @egreg It's treason, then.